# Long lists always end with an ellipsis in debug terminal or when copying

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In the VS Code debug console or the Variable explorer(?) or the watch list pane(?) long lists always end with an ellipsis when displayed. What is really annoying is a right-click-copy also ends up with the ellipsis in the clipboard.

```
→ a = list(range(16))
→ a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, ...]
```

Is there any way to alleviate that and copy or display the entire list? Printing then copying works in the debug console but what about the variable and watch list panes/views?

```
→ print(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I reproduced this problem:

[image]

Thank you for posting this problem here, and we have already submitted this question, let us look forward to the improvement of this function.

Github link: [When debugging python in VSCode, the variable bar cannot display the complete value of the variable.](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/499)

Comment: Thnx, I thought it was just something I couldn't find in the docs.  Should I leave this question up?

Comment: @wwii -This issue is still being processed, and we will update it here if there is any progress.